# How to disable SystemC runtime warnings?

Tags: systemc

I have successfully compiled a SystemC application that I use in order to simulate a CPU when running on a general architecture.
Well my problem is just that, when running the application in order to create the VCD file, the SystemC kernel plots me some warnings.

I get some warning, something like this:

> Warning: (W206) vector contains
>   4-value logic In file:
>   ....\cacheseqproc_vcpp20\systemc-2.2.0\src\sysc\datatypes\bit\sc_proxy.h:1385
>   In process: process.processname @ x ns

Well... the message itself is not important... I put it here just to let you understand better tht this is a warning message thrown at RUNNING time.

Given that I print several important messages during the execution, I would really like not to have these verbose messages by SystemC. How to let this happen?

Comment: Can't you just filter the output (grep)?

Comment: Maybe the [`sc_core::sc_report::suppress_*` methods](http://www.lysium.de/docs/systemc-2.2/docs/html/classsc__core_1_1sc__report.html)?

Comment: @Pilippe: Filtering the output is a solution but I'd rather prefer finding a better solution...

Comment: @Andy: Ok it workd 50% --> It tells me that this method is deprecated ahah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable all warnings:

```
sc_report_handler::set_actions (SC_WARNING, SC_DO_NOTHING);
```

To disable the "vector contains 4-value logic" warning, but leave other warnings enabled:

```
sc_report_handler::set_actions (SC_ID_VECTOR_CONTAINS_LOGIC_VALUE_,
                                SC_DO_NOTHING);
```